# Deleting Content Manually

Tags: 7, nodes, database

If I were to delete the latest row of the node table in the database would all traces of the latest added content be gone from my site without errors from core modules after clearing the cache?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Well, maybe. Well, actually no, not really. You may not get any errors (or you may, completely depends on what you have installed/configured), but you'd definitely have orphaned data. Don't do it, use `node_delete()` instead

Comment: What are these tables that store orphaned data in core?

Comment: I've added an answer with that info

Comment: In what way/where should I use node_delete()?

Comment: If it's not part of your normal application workflow, you could install the devel module and visit /devel/php to run the code. That would be simplest IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a row directly from the node table you can expect:

1. At *best* - you will just have a bunch of orphaned data in the system. Tables containing this orphaned data include, but are by no means limited to,

   - `node_revision`
   - `taxonomy_index`
   - `url_alias`
   - `search_node_links`
   - Any number of `field_data_FIELD_NAME` and `field_revision_FIELD_NAME` tables

   Those are just a few of the core tables that can be affected; there are others, and many contrib modules will install tables to store node-related data. Those will also potentially contain orphaned data.
2. At *worst* - there's no telling how this could affect your site, it completely depends on how it's configured. You might get lucky and experience nothing but the orphaned data, but I wouldn't advise counting on that. Before you do anything, take a backup of your data.